# Can I rollback Dynamic SQL in SQL Server / TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, error-handling, transactions, dynamic-sql

Can I run a dynamic sql in a transaction and roll back using EXEC:

```
exec('SELECT * FROM TableA; SELECT * FROM TableB;');
```

Put this in a Transaction and use the @@error after the exec statement to do rollbacks.

eg. Code

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

   exec('SELECT * FROM TableA; SELECT * FROM TableB;');

   IF @@ERROR != 0
     BEGIN
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
       RETURN
     END
   ELSE
     COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

If there are n dynamic sql statements and the error occurs in n/2 will the first 1 to ((n/2) - 1) statements be rolled back

---

Questions about the first answer

@@Error won't pick up the error most likely 
Which means that it might not pick up the error, which means a transaction might commit? Which defeats the purpose

TRY/CATCH in SQL Server 2005+ 
Yes I am using SQL Server 2005 but haven't used the Try Catch before 
Would doing the below do the trick

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
   BEGIN TRY 
      exec('SELECT * FROM TableA; SELECT * FROM TableB;'); 
      COMMIT TRANSACTION 
   END TRY 
   BEGIN CATCH 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
   END CATCH
```

OR I looked at some more examples on the net

```
BEGIN TRY --Start the Try Block..
 BEGIN TRANSACTION -- Start the transaction..
  exec('SELECT * FROM TableA; SELECT * FROM TableB;');
 COMMIT TRAN -- Transaction Success!
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
      ROLLBACK TRAN --RollBack in case of Error
  RAISERROR(ERROR_MESSAGE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), 1)
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The TXNs belong to the current session/connection and dynamic SQL uses the same context.

However, @@ERROR won't pick up the error most likely: the status has to be checked immediately after the offending statement. I'd use TRY/CATCH, assuming SQL Server 2005+

Edit: The TRY/CATCH should work OK.

Comment: Have extended the question after your answer. About TRY/Catch

Answer (score 0):

Don't take our word for it that try catch will work, test it yourself. Since this is dynamic sql the easiest thing to do is to make the first statement correct (and of course it mneeds to bean update,insert or  delete or there is no need for atransaction) and then make a deliberate syntax error in the second statment. Then test that the update insert or delete in the first statment went through.

I also want to point out that dynamic sql as rule is a poor practice. Does this really need to be dynamic?

Comment: I need to run sql statements from the application itself. i.e. the user can go into the asp.net applciation, gets a box and can run sql statements from there

Comment: @soldieraman: Wow. You are hopefully aware that this "feature" of the application has a vast number of security implications? I can only hope you at least escape or somehow sanitize the user-input before running it against the database?