# Run SQL statements from ASP.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I need to run sql statements from the application itself. i.e. the user can go into the asp.net applciation, gets a box and can run sql statements from there

I am already doing something like this
[Can I rollback Dynamic SQL in SQL Server / TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858329/can-i-rollback-dynamic-sql-in-mssql-tsql/1860334#1860334)

That is running dynamic sql

is there a better way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SQL is certainly the easiest way to do this. The alternative is parameterized SQL, but that would require having your users define and set parameters separately from the T-SQL.

You can simply submit the T-SQL string to SQL Server using the SqlCommand object; there's no real benefit to wrapping it in an EXEC or anything, as in the link you provided.  You can do exception handling on the .NET side.

Also, if you want to support command batches, keep in mind that SqlClient and friends don't understand "GO", which also isn't an actual T-SQL command -- you will need to parse the input and break it into batches yourself.

I'm sure you understand that there is a big security risk in doing this, and that's it's generally not recommended.  You might consider using a connection string that specifies a user with limited permissions, to help control / limit their access.

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT DO THIS. What if the user types in sp_msforeachtable 'truncate table ?'...?

Comment: I know I SHOULDN'T, but I have to..there will be security restrictions put in place. I just need to know how to

Comment: I agree, you SHOULD NOT do this. If your users are trusted well enough to where you'd even consider letting them submit raw SQL statements to your database and they have internet access... then just give them (secure) access to the server via SQL Management studio or a similar 3rd party tool. 

No reason to re-invent the wheel by developing your own SQL tools since there are a LOT of existing tools that aleady work great, but there are MANY reasons NOT to do this via a custom web interface.

Answer (score 0):

RunSQL.aspx utility might help. See [Upload T-SQL and execute at your hosting provider using an ASP.NET page](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=sqlhost&title=UploadAndExecute).